# Using Positional and positioned() in scala parser combinators

Tags: scala, parsing, position, parser-combinators

With separate Lexer and Parser ...

```
class YamlLexical extends StdLexical with YamlTokens with RegexParsers {...
object YamlParser extends StdTokenParsers with YamlTokens with PackratParsers {...
```

... how to get the position of the parsed string into AST classes?

```
(... positioned(elem(...)) * ... )^^ { ... => List( Ast(startpos, parsedtext, ... subnodes ... ), ... )}
```

Answer (score 2):

The type of `positioned` is

```
def positioned[T <: Positional](p: ⇒ Parser[T]): Parser[T]
```

which means that the parsed elements must extend `Positional`. So, for example, `YamlLexical` should be:

```
class YamlLexical extends Positional
```

in that way, any parsed element will automatically have a `pos` which records the position in which it was parsed.