# Can the positioned operator be used with RegexParsers?

Tags: scala

I am using parser combinators to translate quasi-structured log file data to JSON.  I would like to enrich the results with position information as I go so that data elements in the output can be located in the original input file.  When I saw the description of the `positioned` method in the [source code](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators/blob/1.0.x/shared/src/main/scala/scala/util/parsing/combinator/Parsers.scala#L861) and the [API docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/scala-parser-combinators/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers@positioned[T<:scala.util.parsing.input.Positional](p:=>RegexParsers.this.Parser[T]):RegexParsers.this.Parser[T]) I thought the solution was right in front of me but instead I am beating my head against an exception like this:

```
Error:(133, 24) inferred type arguments [String] 
do not conform to method positioned's type 
parameter bounds [T <: scala.util.parsing.input.Positional]
```

Lifting from a [tutorial blog post on parser combinators](https://kerflyn.wordpress.com/2012/08/25/playing-with-scala-parser-combinator/) I expected to be able to say something like:

```
object ReallySimpleParser2 extends RegexParsers {
  def sentence = positioned { hello ~ world }
  def hello = "hello"
  def world = "world"
}
```

This conjecture was inspired by [this blog post](https://enear.github.io/2016/03/31/parser-combinators/) and [its accompanying source code](https://github.com/enear/parser-combinators-tutorial) which was the first complete example I could find that utilized the `positioned` modifer, albeit in a full-blown parser/lexer exercise.  They were able to say things like:

```
def identifier: Parser[IDENTIFIER] = positioned {
  "[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*".r ^^ { str => IDENTIFIER(str) }
}
```

presumably thanks to the magic involved in defining the `IDENTIFIER` type.

So the question is can `positioned` be used out of the box with a `RegexParser`?  If so, how, and if not, what's the minimum scaffolding required to utilize `positioned` with a `RegexParser`?

Comment: I also meant to mention that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919068/using-positional-and-positioned-in-scala-parser-combinators may point the way, although too obliquely for me.

Answer (score 1):

`positioned` can only wrap a parser, that produces a subclass of `Positional`. Here is an example:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers
import scala.util.parsing.input.Positional

case class Content(value: String) extends Positional

object ReallySimpleParser2 extends RegexParsers {
  def sentence = positioned { hello ~ world ^^ { case a ~ b => Content(s"$a $b") } }
  def hello = "hello"
  def world = "world"
}
```

So in the second example `IDENTIFIER` must extend `Positional`.